# Grok Learning: Halve this TypeError

Tags: python

I have to write a program that reads in a whole number and prints out that number divided by two. This is my code:

```
a= int(input("Number: "))
h= a/2
print("Half number: " + h)
```

But I keep getting this

```
Number: 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "program.py", line 3, in <module>
print("Half number: " + h)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code and I have no idea what the error is. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Try `print("Half number: ", h)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
"Half number: " + h
```

is trying to add a string to a float.  You can add strings to strings:

```
"This string" + ", then this string"
```

and floats to floats:

```
100.0 + 16.8
```

but Python isn't willing to let you add strings and floats.  (In the error message above, Python has processed the first string and the addition, and it now expects a string -- that's why you get the error that it can't -- or at least won't -- convert a 'float' number to a string.)

You can tell Python this is what you really want it to do in a few ways.  One is to use the built-in str() function which converts any object to some reasonable string representation, ready to be added to another string:

```
 h = 100
 "You can add a string to this: " + str(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

a= int(input("Number: "))

h= a/2

print('Half number:', h)
Without the spaces in between though

Comment: Could you please include a brief explanation of the code and how it solves the problem in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to do it.

Here's a sample solution from Grok Learning:

```
n = int(input('Number: '))
print('Half number:', n/2)
```

Here's my explanation below:

As you might've  already guessed, `n` here is a variable. And in this code, we will be assigning some information to `n`. `int(input('Number '))` is the statement that Python will then read, and follow. `int()` tells Python that the input will be an integer, and `input()` allows the user to input whatever they would like to input. `n/2` is simply another way of saying *"n divided by two"*. `print()` tells Python to print a statement, and so `print('Half number:', n/2)` will print out that "Half number" is simply just *half of the number entered above.*

Here's an example of what the output should look like:

```
Number: 6
Half number: 3
```

(In that example, the input was *6*.)

So, yes, I know that you may already know this stuff but I am leaving this information for people who may visit this website in the future. The error that you had was that you used a `+`, when you should've used a `,`. Python is pretty strict when it comes to processing what you're saying, so it didn't allow you to put a `str` and an `int` together using a `+`. So next time, remember to use a `,`.

I hope this helps you.